# Where are my timestamps getting "messed up"?

Tags: postgresql, jodatime, jooq

Since I am already getting down voted I decided to give some more details to my problem.

My problem is that I want to store *times*. Times *only* for easy comparison. To me it makes sense to define it as following:

```
00:00:00 = (long) 0L
24:00:00 = (long) 24*60*60*1000L
```

The PostgreSQL [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html) says about `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` this:

```
time [ (p) ] [ without time zone ] 
   8 bytes | time of day (no date) | 00:00:00 - 24:00:00 | 1 microsecond / 14 digits
```

But for some reason, somewhere along the way from my database to my web application the timestamps are getting messed up.

In the following I want to show you that I am storing `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, mapped from `LocalTime` (jodatime), into my database and afterwards fetch it back.

Fetching it back from the database and mapping it back into a `LocalTime` object will give me something like `23 Feb 2016 08:00:00 GMT` which is
`1456214400000` and that is `> 24*60*60*1000`.

There are 3 to 4 options:

1. PostgresSQL stores actually the whole `TIMESTAMP` and shows `HH:mm:ss` just for presentation
2. jodatime is inventing things here that are not there.
3. (very unlikely) The mapper I am using does more than I tell him. But that is unlikely since the mapper does **not** touch anything.
4. (probably true) I myself mess things up somehow.

---

**More details:**

I decided to add some more details. I am creating a record for my table `shop_times`

```java
private Long createShopTimes(Long shopId, DateTime dayFrom, DateTime dayTo, LocalTime timeFrom, LocalTime timeTo, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, ShopTimesType shopTimesType) {

    Long timePeriodId = this.ctx.insertInto(SHOP_TIMES)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.SHOP_ID, shopId)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.DAY_OF_WEEK_ID, dayOfWeek)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.SHOP_TIMES_TYPE_ID, shopTimesType)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.DAY_FROM, dayFrom)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.DAY_TO, dayTo)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.TIME_FROM, timeFrom)
            .set(SHOP_TIMES.TIME_TO, timeTo)
            .returning(SHOP_TIMES.ID)
            .fetchOne().getValue(SHOP_TIMES.ID);

    List<ShopTimesRecord> fetchInto = this.ctx.select(
            SHOP_TIMES.TIME_FROM,
            SHOP_TIMES.TIME_TO
            )
            .from(SHOP_TIMES)
            .fetchInto(ShopTimesRecord.class);

    for (ShopTimesRecord shopTimesRecord : fetchInto) {

        if(shopTimesRecord.getTimeFrom().toDateTimeToday().getMillis() > 24*60*60*1000L) {
            System.err.println("This should not happen..");
        }

        Date from = new Date(shopTimesRecord.getTimeFrom().toDateTimeToday().getMillis());
        Date to = new Date(shopTimesRecord.getTimeTo().toDateTimeToday().getMillis());

        System.out.println(from.toGMTString());
        System.out.println(shopTimesRecord.getTimeFrom().toDateTimeToday().getMillis());

        System.out.println(to.toGMTString());
        System.out.println(shopTimesRecord.getTimeTo().toDateTimeToday().getMillis());
    }

    return timePeriodId;
}
```

As you can see, I am getting something that I would not expect at this point:

```
This should not happen..
23 Feb 2016 08:00:00 GMT
1456214400000
23 Feb 2016 20:00:00 GMT
1456257600000
```

---

This is the table `shop_times` that I am using to store timing information:

```sql
CREATE TABLE shop_times (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,

    -- FOREIGN KEYS

    shop_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_times__shop
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop(id),

    shop_times_type_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_shop_times__shop_times_type
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_times_type_id)
        REFERENCES shop_times_type(id),

    day_of_week_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_times__day_of_week
        FOREIGN KEY (day_of_week_id)
        REFERENCES day_of_week(id),

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    day_from TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    day_to TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

    time_from TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    time_to TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

    -- CONSTRAINTS

    CHECK(day_from < day_to),

    CHECK(time_from < time_to)

);
```

The mapper I am using. But as you can see it is just taking the time it gets and passes it further;

```java
public class TimeWithoutTzToJodaLocalTimeConverter implements Converter<Time, LocalTime> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2736422625956918206L;

    @Override
    public LocalTime from(Time timestamp) {
        LocalTime dateTime = new LocalTime(timestamp.getTime());
        return dateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public Time to(LocalTime localTime) {
        Time time = new Time(localTime.toDateTimeToday().getMillis());
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Time> fromType() {
        return Time.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<LocalTime> toType() {
        return LocalTime.class;
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe that the `Calendar` object in Java also allows any arbitrary number of hours to be assigned to it.  Maybe there is a common reason for this.

Comment: Your `CHECK` is probably not doing what you think it's doing... `TO_TIMESTAMP(24*60*60*1000)` is `'1972-09-27 10:00:00'`.

Comment: @NickBarnes Okay, good point. But this does not solve the issue as it still appears to accept `2016-09-27 10:00:00` as well. At least that is what I get if I fetch it.

Comment: @displayname: Why shouln't it accept that? `10:00:00` is not larger that `24:00:00`

Comment: What is that check constraint supposed to do? Why don't you simply use `check (time_from < time '23:00:00')` (or whatever maximum time you want to enforce)

Comment: @NickBarnes I made an update to my question with a lot more information and code to potentially reproduce what I am seeing. It is possible that it's not PostgreSQLs fault but I have not actual explanation for what I get out of it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please see my updated question.

Comment: Why are you casting the `time_from` and `time_to` columns in the check constraint? Those columns are already defined as `time` so there is no need to cast them. `CHECK(time_from < time_to)` should work just fine.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I agree. What you see are remains from a time where I tried to find out what is happening here.

Comment: @displayname: `toDateTimeToday()` attaches today's date to the time from the database to produce a `DateTime`. `getMillis()` converts this `DateTime` to the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. This is clearly going to be well over 24 hours...

Comment: @NickBarnes It appears that it was option `4.` all along.. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a full DateTime:

```
.toDateTimeToday()
```

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/TimeOfDay.html#toDateTimeToday%28%29

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - don't believe you.

```
=> SELECT '24:00:00'::time without time zone;
   time   
----------
 24:00:00
(1 row)

=> SELECT '24:00:01'::time without time zone;
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24:00:01"
LINE 1: SELECT '24:00:01'::time without time zone;
```

Comment: I updated my question. It is very likely that I make a mistake somewhere but I can't see where actually. Please check it out.

Comment: Looking at the other answers/comments and your expanded question, it seems to be something in your Java stack that's doing this (not a Java user, so can't comment on where). It's always useful to be able to check the different layers though, and luckily, with an SQL RDBMS this is fairly simple.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it was in fact me using `toDateTimeToday()` where I shouldn't use it :/